# How to make this DataList show the quizzes that were sent to the users?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing an intranet web application which is a Quiz Engine. I have a DataList that shows the available quizzes in the system with showing a short description about each one of them. Now this DataList shows all the quizzes in the Database. What I want is the following: since I have the following database design:

Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description, IsSent

*The QuizID is the primary key in that table. IsSent is a flag/boolean that will be true if the quiz was sent to the users.*

Instead of showing all the available quizzes in the database, I want to let this DataList to show only the quiz when it is sent to the users by starting with last sending quiz. 
Is this related to the query that I am using right now?

My query is:

```
SELECT [Title], [Description], [QuizID] FROM [Quiz]
```

If yes, could you please help me with modifying it?

My ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink
                                            ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "StartQuiz.aspx?testid=" + Eval("QuizID") %>'
                                            Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:HyperLink><br />
                                    &nbsp;<asp:Label
                                        ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" CssClass="generaltext" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
                                    <br />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                SelectCommand="SELECT [Title], [Description], [QuizID] FROM [Quiz]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to let this DataList to show only the quiz when it is sent to
>   the users by **starting with last sending quiz**

- It depends how you are tracking 'last sending quiz' in your database
  table
- You can either check the last sent quiz ordered by id in descending order

> SELECT [Title], [Description], [QuizID],[IsSent] FROM [Quiz] where
>   [IsSent]=1 order by [QuizID] DESC

- You can also track your last sent quizes by introducing a new column say 'LastModified' in your table & keep a date timestamp there so you could track which quiz was last sent from query

> SELECT [Title], [Description], [QuizID],[IsSent],[LastUpdated] FROM [Quiz] where
>   [IsSent]=1 order by [LastUpdated] DESC

Comment: There's a chance that the upper-cased "timestamp" word in your post will mislead unaware people into thinking that the existing [SQL Server `timestamp` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) has anything to do with date & time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Your answer is useful and explained very well.